# Kendo-UI Dropdown List separator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui

I want to add a separator to the kendo UI dropdown list, does kendo support this?

what I came up with as a work around was using jquery's insertBefore or appending at a specific li tag, hooking directly onto the dropdown list's DOM.

Here is the example:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
open: function (e) {
    //Add only if not exists
    if ($("#separatorReceiveType").length == 0) {
        //Append separator in kendo UI
        $("<li id='separatorReceiveType'><hr></li>").insertBefore($("#idDropdownReceiveType_listbox").children().last());
    }
},
```

Comment: I think you need a Template for your List Items, so you can print a line or sth

Comment: It's a shame that this widget doesn't support such a silly feature like this. http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/127393-telerik-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/7015513-add-separator-delimiter-functionality-to-the-ken

Comment: Dang okay, well that sucks... thanks for the reply guys. Will have to stick to classic old dom manipulation. the horizontal line with a kendo class looks okay in the dropdown though, will have to use it till telerik decides to support this.